# Netty deployment with just JRE

Tags: java, netty

I'm interested in using Netty for network communication between a client on one computer and a server on another. The Netty documentation says that the JDK is required to run Netty. However, I'm developing an app that will run on a variety of customer computers, most of which will just have the JRE, not the JDK. I suspect that what the Netty documentation really means is that the JDK (1.5 or 1.6 I think) is required to DEVELOP netty based applications, the deployed application can be run on computers with just the JRE. Is this the case? Can someone experienced with Netty confirm this?

Unfortunately Netty has no easy place to ask this question. the forum just redirects to some user group list that provides some hellish infinite loop of mailing list registration and password requests.

This should be an easy question to answer for anyone who has experience deploing netty based applications on customer computers.

Answer (score 2):

Just the JRE is required to run your app.  You want need the JDK to run your app.

Answer (score 2):

Netty is pure java implementation and what you say is correct, it requires JDK to develop server and client in it. But for running the developed applications you only need a JRE, no JDK is required.

Regarding registering to the user group. Try the following [link](http://www.jboss.org/netty/community.html), on the top right you have register option and I think the JBoss website has some issue with certain browsers.. try using a different web browser and it might work out for you.

Regards,
Abraham.